# comparing three cells in openoffice calc. (i'd be happy with 2)

Tags: openoffice-calc

I need to do a simple function that is driving me nuts.
I have 3 columns with cells filled as follows.

I2 Y
I3 N
I4 Y

I am looking for every row that has N N N. I'm trying to formulate it so I can do a visual inspection but (baby steps) my first stage is failing. I'm trying

=IF(I2='N';'Y';'N')

In this case the output should be 'Y', Instead I'm getting #VALUE.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using double quotes and that should do it

```
=IF(A1="y";"y";"n")
```

this works for me

Comment: Thanks any ideas why  the next step
IF(I2="N" & H2="N" & G2 ="N" ;"Y";"")
OR
IF(I2=G2 & H2 = G2 ;"Y";"")

Comment: I never realised you could chain them together like that. I come from an excel background where I have always nested them. Had a quick play around though and found an answer. you weren't far away        =IF((G2="N")  AND  (H2="N")  AND  (I2="N");"Y";"N")

Comment: Ok, thanks, my final formula is 

=IF((I2=G2)  AND  (H2 = G2) ;"Y";"")

Seems & != AND